# php preg_match fails when used with a variable

Tags: php, regex

Excuse me, I am making a terrible mistake somewhere, but this is the situaton:

In php i have:

```
$ln = "A/RADIUS ADMITS VALUE 20";
$trg = "A/RADIUS";
$matches = array();
$zz = preg_match('#$trg\sADMITS\s(VALUE)\s([^\s]+)#',$ln,$matches);
```

I want to capture the word `"VALUE"` without quotes and the last word, here the string 20, given by ([^\s]+) . That is not a whitespace repeated more than once right?

But `$zz` is 0, indicating no match and `$matches` is empty. I also tried with

```
 $zz = preg_match('#'.$trg.'\sADMITS\s(VALUE)\s([^\s]+)#',$ln,$matches);
```

same problem.

Where is the mistake I am stupidly making?

Comment: [`preg_quote($trg, '#')`](http://www.php.net/preg_quote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes to embed the `$trg` variable in the string, which only works when using double quotes to enclose the string. This should work:

```
$zz = preg_match("#$trg\sADMITS\s(VALUE)\s([^\s]+)#",$ln,$matches);
```

Comment: @h2ooooooo Odd, as I can confirm it working as expected. See: http://3v4l.org/ETYd5

Comment: while using single quote then using the '.' to concat the variable is NOT working, embedding the variable in a double quoted string IS working. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Yet another quetion, about  
$zz = preg_match('#'.$trg.'\sADMITS\s(VALUE)\s([^\s]+)#', $ln , $matches);
failing : is it a bug in PHP ? should I file a report?